# What can be said about the set of points that makes the MVT "works"?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, reference-request

Consider a (real-valued) function $f$ that is differentiable on an open interval $I$ of $\mathbb R$.

For $a\neq b$ in $\mathbb R$, we consider $S_{a,b}=\left\{ x\in I\; \middle|\; f'(x)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\;  \right\}$. $S_{a,b}$ is non empty by the Mean Value Theorem.

Let now $\displaystyle S=\bigcup_{a\neq b \in I}S_{a,b}$

**What can be said about $S$**?

Has this set been studied before? Is $S$ an interval? Is $S$ open?

Clearly, $S$ is a subset of $I$ but the inclusion can be strict. For example, if $f(x)=x^3$, we have $0\notin S$.  This example also shows that $S$ is not always an interval.

Note: feel free to add conditions on $f$ if it allows $S$ to have nice properties.

Comment: @M.Winter: do you have an example where $S$ is a single point?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are assumed to vary on $I$ in the definition of $S$. I'll edit

Comment: I realized I misunderstood the question. Interesting one! Maybe rename the set $S$ to avoid confusion with $S(a,b)$ when dropping the paramters.

Comment: $S$ is dense in $I$. For any open interval $(a,b)\subseteq I$, we have $S\cap(a,b)\not=\varnothing$.

Comment: You probably meant that $S= I$ is not true in general instead of "clearly $S\subsetneq I$", right? E.g. $f(x)=x^2$ on $I=(-1,1)$ has $S=(-1,1)$.

Comment: If $I$ is an open  interval and $f''$ never vanishes on $I$ then $S=I$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/776766/72031

Comment: @M.Winter: you are right. I corrected my mistake

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at this question more geometrically. Start with a point $x$ and calculate derivative of $f$ at $x$ and hence tangent line at $(x,f(x))$. Allow the tangent line be translated up or down. If after translation, the line cuts the graph of $f$ at two distinct points $(a,f(a)),(b,f(b))$ such that $a\lt x\lt b$, then $x\in S$ by definition.

There is a nice property of the function $f$ that guarantees the existence of such points $a,b$. If $f$ is locally convex (resp. concave) around $p$ (i.e. $f$ is convex (resp. concave) on an open interval $U$ containing $p$), then such $a,b$ must exist. Note that all points in $U$ are also in $S$ because they have the same property as $x$, thus making $x$ an interior point of $S$.

For an informal proof of the claim that local convexity (resp. concavity) is sufficient, start by picking two points $p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon$ for some small enough $\varepsilon\gt0$. Draw the tangent line of $f$ at $p$, and pick the segment bounded by the two vertical lines $x=p-\varepsilon$ and $x=p+\varepsilon$. Due to convexity (resp. concavity), the point $(p,f(p))$ lies below (resp. above) the line segment joining $(p-\varepsilon,f(p-\varepsilon))$ and $(p+\varepsilon,f(p+\varepsilon))$. So move the tangent segment up (resp. down) until it touches one of the two points $(p-\varepsilon,f(p-\varepsilon)),(p+\varepsilon,f(p+\varepsilon))$. Use intermediate value theorem (as $f$ is continuous) to conclude that the moved tangent segment cuts the graph of $f$ at another point $(p',f(p'))$ with $p\lt p'\le p+\varepsilon$ if the moving tangent segment touches $(p-\varepsilon,f(p-\varepsilon))$ first, and $p-\varepsilon\le p'\lt p$ if if the moving tangent segment touches $(p+\varepsilon,f(p+\varepsilon))$ first.

These arguments also shows why it is possible that $0\notin S$ for $f(x)=x^3$ and not for other points.. $0$ is an inflection point of $x^3$, where it is possible that $0\notin S$.

Comment: The fact you think obvious does require a proof. See the linked answer in my comments to the question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Informal proof added.

Answer (score 2):

For any $y$ define

$$g_y(x) = f(x) - f'(y) (x-y).$$

Clearly $g_y'(y) = 0$, so

- either $y$ is a local extremum, and in this case clearly $y \in S$.
- or $y$ is not an extremum, which is equivalent to $g_y'$ (and so also f') having an strict extremum at $y$ (i.e., as @edm showed, $f$ is strictly concave or strictly convex at that point).

This means that $\{x: f' \, \text{does not have a strict extremum at } x\} \subset S$. The other inclusion is not true: take for example $f = e^{x^2} \sin (x)$, where $S = \mathbb R$, but $f''$ vanishes in many places.