# Proving L'Hospital's theorem using the Generalized Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The following is the theorem from [Understanding Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1493927116) by Stephen Abbott.

Thm 5.3.6 : (L'Hospital's rule: $0/0$ case) Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous on an interval containing $a$, and assume $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on this interval with the possible exception of the point $c$. If $f(c)=g(c)=0$ and $g^{\prime}(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\neq c$, then

$$\lim\limits_{x\to c}\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)} = L \implies \lim\limits_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$$

In the proof, the author says that "The argument follows from a straightforward application of the generalized mean value theorem". However, I am failing to see any such "straightforward" argument.

As given in the same book, the Generalized Mean value Theorem (GMVT), if $f$ and $g$ are continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, then there exists a point $c\in (a,b)$ where

$$[f(b)-f(a)]g^{\prime}(c)=[g(b)-g(a)]f^{\prime}(c)$$

To use it to prove the L'Hospital's rule, one must first try to see whether a closed interval $[a, b]$ around $c$ could be constructed so that $c$ will satisfy the mean value theorem. However, I think that [the converse doesn't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776693/converse-of-mean-value-theorem).Even if it did, it is not clear to me how would one proceed to prove the required theorem. Could someone please help me?

Comment: For $x \neq c$, you have $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{g(x) - g(c)}.$$ Now apply the GMVT with $a = x$, $b = c$, and call the $c$ in the statement of the GMVT (which has nothing to do with the $c$ in the statement of L'H) for example $y$ (or $\xi$).

Comment: @DanielFischer: I am still not clear about it. If I take limit as $x\to c$ (and has to be $c$ because that is where $f$ and $g$ are $0$), then I don't see any way to get the L'Hospital's rule. It would basically say
$$\lim\limits_{x\to c}\frac{f^{\prime}(\xi)}{f^{\prime}(\xi)} = L$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon > 0$ we want to show the existence of a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\biggl\lvert \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - L \biggr\rvert < \varepsilon$$
for $0 < \lvert x - c\rvert < \delta$ (and $x$ belonging to the interval). By the assumption
$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$$
there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\biggl\lvert \frac{f'(y)}{g'(y)} - L \biggr\rvert < \varepsilon$$
for all $y$ in the interval with $0 < \lvert y - c\rvert < \delta$. The generalised mean value theorem shows that this same $\delta$ also works for $f(x)/g(x)$, since for
$0 < \lvert x - c\rvert < \delta$ we have
\begin{align}
\biggl\lvert \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - L\biggr\rvert
&= \biggl\lvert \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{g(x) - g(c)} - L\biggr\rvert \\
&= \biggl\lvert \frac{f'(y)}{g'(y)} - L \biggr\rvert \\
&< \varepsilon
\end{align}
for some $y \in (c,x)$ or $y \in (x,c)$, depending on whether $x > c$ or $x < c$.

Thus, since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, it follows that
$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L.$$